# Yahoo News App like slanted custom ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I know this question has been asked before and I am unable to get a good solution so far.

I need to create a custom ImageView like the one use in the yahoo news app like below screenshot.

[image]

In the View hierarchy in the right, you can see its an imageview only. Below there is a framelayout and I attached a screenshot of that as well.

[image]

I don't think this is achieved using a layer-list, which can draw custom shapes on top of  views.

So how to create a custom imageview with custom shape like this in android?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, It might [help](https://github.com/HeZaiJin/SlantedTextView)

Comment: @Nisarg i ll check it